# Merge all duplicate cells in entire worksheet - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to build a macro which will iterate through `Activeworkbook/Activeworksheet`& `Range("A1:" & LastColumn & LastRow)` and merge all duplicates in each column. The best starting point I could find was this post --> [fastest way to merge duplicate cells in without looping Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45737497/fastest-way-to-merge-duplicate-cells-in-without-looping-excel/45739951#comment104755961_45739951)

But, like the OP comments on @PEH's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45739951/5079799 I get the following error `Application defined error` on the line `Set R = .Range(Join(arr, ","))`.

Does anybody have the fix and/or a better/alternative way to merge duplicates in a column?

**Code from answer:**

```
Sub MergeCellsNew()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim n As Name
    Dim fc As FormatCondition
    Dim Rng As Range, R As Range
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim I&, J&
    Dim arr As Variant

    ReDim arr(1 To 1) As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("tst")
        Set Rng = .Range("A2:D11")
        lRow = Rng.End(xlDown).Row

        For J = 1 To 4
            I = 2 'I = Rng.Row   to automatically start at the first row of Rng
            Do While I <= lRow
                Set R = .Cells(I, J) 'remember start cell

                'run this loop as long as duplicates found next to the start cell
                Do While Trim(UCase(.Cells(I, J))) = Trim(UCase(.Cells(I + 1, J)))
                    Set R = R.Resize(R.Rows.Count + 1) 'and resize R + 1
                    I = I + 1
                Loop

                'now if R is bigger than one cell there are duplicates we want to add to the arr
                'this way single cells are not added to the arr
                If R.Rows.Count > 1 Then
                    arr(UBound(arr)) = R.Address
                    ReDim Preserve arr(1 To UBound(arr) + 1)
                End If
                I = I + 1
            Loop
        Next J
        ReDim Preserve arr(1 To UBound(arr) - 1)

        Set R = .Range(Join(arr, ","))
        With R
            .Merge
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With

        Stop
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't know the issue with the code I found and posted in OP. I did find awesome solutions on https://www.extendoffice.com and modified it to suit my needs as found below.

**Test:**

```
Sub MergeTest()
 Dim wsrng As Range
 Set wsrng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
 Call MergeWS(wsrng)
 'Call UnMergeWS(wsrng)
End Sub
```

**Merge:**

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1138-excel-merge-same-value.html

```
Function MergeWS(WorkRng As Range)
Dim Rng As Range, xCell As Range
Dim xRows As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
xRows = WorkRng.Rows.Count
For Each Rng In WorkRng.Columns
    For i = 1 To xRows - 1
        For j = i + 1 To xRows
            If Rng.Cells(i, 1).Value <> Rng.Cells(j, 1).Value Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        With WorkRng.Parent.Range(Rng.Cells(i, 1), Rng.Cells(j - 1, 1))
            .Merge
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
        i = j - 1
    Next
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function
```

**UnMerge:**

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1139-excel-unmerge-cells-and-fill.html

```
Function UnMergeWS(WorkRng As Range)
Dim Rng As Range, xCell As Range
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each Rng In WorkRng
    If Rng.MergeCells Then
        With Rng.MergeArea
            .UnMerge
            .Formula = Rng.Formula
        End With
    End If
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function
```

https://www.freesoftwareservers.com/display/FREES/Merge+and+UnMerge+cells+-+Excel+VBA

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see with the methods outlined above is that it relies on duplicate data existing in an adjacent cell in the column. What if the duplicates are scattered in the column?

Here's an example where each column is examined by creating a `Dictionary` of all the values. Since each value must be unique (as the Key), then duplicates are removed with a list of just the unique Keys. Then it's just a matter of clearing the column of the previous data and copying the unique data back to the worksheet.

```
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveColumnDupes()
    Dim lastCol As Long
    With Sheet1
        lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        Dim c As Long
        For c = 1 To lastCol
            Dim columnDict As Dictionary
            Set columnDict = CreateColumnDictionary(Sheet1, c)
            If columnDict is Nothing then Exit For

            '--- clear the existing data and replace with the cleaned up data
            .Range("A1").Offset(, c - 1).Resize(.Rows.Count, 1).Clear
            .Range("A1").Offset(, c - 1).Resize(columnDict.Count, 1) = KeysToArray(columnDict)
        Next c
    End With
End Sub

Private Function CreateColumnDictionary(ByRef ws As Worksheet, _
                                        ByVal colIndex As Long) As Dictionary
    Dim colDict As Dictionary
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, colIndex).End(xlUp).Row
        If lastRow = 1 Then
            '--- can't create a dictionary with no data, so exit
            Set colDict = Nothing
        Else
            Set colDict = New Dictionary
            Dim i As Long
            For i = 1 To lastRow
                If Not colDict.Exists(.Cells(i, colIndex).Value) Then
                    colDict.Add .Cells(i, colIndex).Value, i
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    End With
    Set CreateColumnDictionary = colDict
End Function

Private Function KeysToArray(ByRef thisDict As Dictionary) As Variant
    Dim newArray As Variant
    ReDim newArray(1 To thisDict.Count, 1 To 1)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To thisDict.Count
        newArray(i, 1) = thisDict.Keys(i - 1)
    Next i
    KeysToArray = newArray
End Function
```

Comment: Hmm I'll have to test, leaving for the day, but moving data around to different worksheets might not work as expected. Imagine I have cells `A1:A4` to merge but also `B2:B3`. I want the cells merged but the rows to stay in position.

Comment: This gave error `User-defined type not defined` which I'm guessing means I have to enable a reference library. I don't use code that requires enabling anything as my code must be portable. Thank you though!